# Unit Testing Angular 5 scroll event triggers after whenStable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, scroll, dom-events

I have not been able to find out why this test does not work. Given my sample code below. When I am unit testing changes made when scrolling a child DIV element in a component. The event handler triggers as expected but the async\whenStable does not wait for the Zone task to complete, and the task triggers when the test is complete.

I have tried assigning the event with Renderer2.listen with exactly the same result.

**App.Component.ts**

```
import { Component, Renderer2, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('message') messageBox: HTMLDivElement;
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  onScroll() {
     this.renderer.setStyle(this.messageBox, 'color', 'blue');
  }
}
```

**App.Component.html**

```
<div class="scrollWindow" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
  <div class="scrollContent">Bacon ipsum dolor amet short ribs jowl ball tip turkey sirloin meatloaf ground round capicola pork belly pork chop doner
    flank brisket boudin. Pork chop sausage alcatra meatloaf pork belly meatball bacon tongue tenderloin pastrami hamburger
    pork ribeye andouille biltong. Doner bresaola biltong chicken cupim ham. Beef ribs drumstick ground round bresaola prosciutto
    andouille, pork belly beef flank. Bacon beef cupim turkey, buffalo sausage ham tongue rump ground round doner swine pastrami
    chuck.
  </div>
</div>
<p #message>This is a message</p>
```

**App.Component.css**

```
.scrollWindow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.scrollContent {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

**App.Component.spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const container = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.scrollWindow'));

    container.nativeElement.scrollLeft = 50;
    expect(container.nativeElement.scrollLeft).toEqual(50);

    container.nativeElement.scroll();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      const message = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('p'));
      expect(message.styles.color).toEqual('blue');
    });
  }));
});
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the `fixture.detectChanges();`inside the `fixture.whenStable().then(() => {...})` like in the tutorial https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-async

Comment: Or using fakeAsync() with tick()?

Comment: Yes I have tried both these.

Comment: And what you're trying to test works when you execute it manually; the implementation is correct?

Comment: Yes the implementation is fine. however the scroll implementation triggers several effects in our application so we need a solid test to verify that its happening

Comment: It turns out I needed to use the line container.triggerEventHandler('scroll', null); instead on container.nativeElement.scroll();

Answer (score 8):

I was able to trigger the scroll event simply using:

```js
page.myElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('scroll'));
```

Given that my `page.myElement` is linked to my HTML element

```html
<div id='my-element' (scroll)="onScroll()">
```

This is a better approach rather then directly calling `component.onScroll()` from the unit test.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I needed to use the line

```
container.triggerEventHandler('scroll', null);
```

instead of

```
container.nativeElement.scroll();
```

Comment: Good to know. I think nativeElement.scroll is an event-map, not a trigger..